# How to get values of fields of schema in SDL Tridion using core services?

Tags: schema, tridion

I want to get values of fields of schema in sdl tridion using core services
Camn anyone help me out of this?

Comment: Please see your other question for an answer and then close this one.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443439/how-to-set-content-to-a-component-without-loading-xml-in-sdl-tridion-using-core

Comment: Considering Aquarius24's follow-up comments, it does seem as though this question is a duplicate of the one referenced by Puf. @Aquarius24 - isn't that right? The only difference is get vs. set. As it turns out, there seems to be better support for get than set, but the answer in both cases is that you shouldn't be trying so hard to avoid XML.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please clarify what you meant my Schema Field Value? To Get the Schema Fields list you can use core service ReadSchemaFields method.

```
SchemaFieldsData schemaFieldsData = _coreServiceClient.ReadSchemaFields(schemaId, false, null);

ItemFieldDefinitionData firstField = schemaFieldsData.Fields.First<ItemFieldDefinitionData>();

var fieldName = firstField.Name;
```

Comment: @ Bappi .. thanks for concern I am creating component using core service, so i want to assign data to its fields without using xml.
How can be achieve it?
any help?

Comment: You can't. But I think you already posted that same question and I just answered it.

Comment: @ puf ya thanks i got it. that was really useful for me thanks a lot once again